# Asp.net MVC3 reporting system

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting

I am building a new asp.net MVC3 web application for reporting and I want to know the best way to create reports.

I've tried to use Crystal reports but its has some issues in implementation and styling so Is there is a free or customized solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of searching in google i found a good solution that meets my needs that is a free open source tool [here](http://doddlereport.codeplex.com/) called doddleReports it creates pdf, excel, csv comma delimited, HTML report

Answer (score 0):

I have used [worddocgenerator.codeplex.com](http://worddocgenerator.codeplex.com/) as a reporting tool in one lightweight ASP.NET application. It allows you to generate data bound content with very few code.

[image]

To preview reports you can use the [Open Xml Viewer](http://openxmlviewer.codeplex.com/)

Comment: that tool creating a word document how to embed that in html web page also it depends in word documents to generate templates that is a problem too